# Triple Integrals - When does order of integration not matter?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, order-of-integration

In general, I know that for the triple integral $$\iiint f(x,y,z)dxdydz$$ the order of integration cannot be changed arbitrarily. However, if we know that the bounds are constants and that $$f(x,y,z)=f(x)g(y)h(z)$$ then can we rewrite the triple integral as $$\int f(x)dx \cdot \int g(y)dy \cdot \int h(z)dz$$ with the respective bounds?

I've seen several questions on MathStackExchange regarding change of order for triple integrals with nonconstant bounds, but I just wanted to verify that this is correct because I've encountered this type of integral several times in my physics course. Thanks!

Comment: I disagree with your initial premise. As long as you take adequate care with the boundaries of the volume over which you are carrying out the integration, then order of integration should not have any influence on the answer.

Comment: Since it's physics, if I recall correctly, you're allowed to convert multidimensional to iterated integrals and change order of integration whenever you please as long as the answer is clearly correct at the end :) 
 (you can also change $+$ signs to $-$ signs and forget or add in factors of $2\pi$ as needed).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen That was precisely my reasoning. For example, the mass of an object of specified dimensions, where density is any 'reasonable' function of position can be calculated by a volume integral of the objects local density. And its mass cant change dependent on how you do the 'slicing' and 'dicing'.

Comment: @Penguino I wasn't intending that as a serious remark. There are a lot of examples where changing the order of integration doesn't work (although it generally works with positive integrands). See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)#Basic_theorems (Also OP: see the last theorem here).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I guess I was oversimplifying a little, but if the questioner is dealing with physics as they suggest in their last paragraph then all should be good. As there are no real infinities or discontinuities in physics.

Comment: @Penguino Sometimes in physics you do get trouble with order of limits issues when taking infinite limits (usually happens on a conceptually high level like taking thermodynamic or continuum limits, though I do recall one and only one situation where it happened to me in a routine calculation). But yes, OP is probably safe (and guaranteed safe if those bounds and functions are finite).

Comment: @Penguino, what I meant was that in general you cannot simply switch the order of integration without having to account for the change in the boundaries. My initial premise was poorly worded. Thank you both for explaining the subtleties of the problem, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\int_a^b\int_c^d\int_s^t f(x)g(y)h(z) dzdydx= \int_a^b\int_c^d\left(\int_s^t f(x)g(y)h(z)dz\right)dydx$ and, since f(x) and g(y) do not depend upon z, that is the same as $\int_a^b\int_c^df(x)g(y)\left(\int_s^t f(x)g(y)h(z)dz\right)dydx$.  Now, $\int_s^t h(z)dz$ is a number, call it "P", so we can factor it out of the integral and write $P\int_a^b\int_c^d f(x)g(y) dydz= P\int_a^b f(x)\left(\int_c^d g(y)dy\right)dx$ and do the same thing again.